# Transfer data using peer to peer within same app on different devices

Tags: android, networking, p2p

I am new to this development process please help me out. I am developing an application in which i have a list of words under a user profile.

Let us suppose i have two devices A and B, both want to share their words-list with each other. 
If A is sender then B act as receiver and vice versa.

So how can they communicate (Share Data) with one another using wifi direct without internet connectivity.

I have reached upto  level that array of words created now i donot know how to proceed further client and server in same app. stuck in problem 
Any Example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use solutions such as Parse ( it is closing now, but you can still setup you own server). You make queries as with ordinary database, but can save/fetch data on any device (android/iOs). It also has good sample project and comprehensive documentation (https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide).

Comment: I want to share data with other device in same app @Alex Shutov

Comment: Please give solution